# How to alert success message in modal form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I'm new to ajax/jquery. I want to use sweetalert on my website, i set it up as in tutorial, but when i open modal form and click `send` button, it goes to another page, page `send.php`.

Here my form:

```
   <form  id="contactForm1" action="send.php" method="post">
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="text">Message1</label>
      <textarea id="message1" class="field" required name="message1" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>
<div class="field-block">
        <label for="text">Message2</label>
        <textarea id="message2" class="field" required name="message2" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="text">Message3</label>
        <textarea id="message3" class="field" required name="message3" rows="4" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>

      <button id="button" class="button" type="submit">Отправить</button>
      <div class="result">
        <span id="answer"></span>
        <span id="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif" alt=""></span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

inside this form sweetalert doesn't work, but outside of form it's working.

Here sweetalert jquery and ajax request:

```
<script>

            $("#contactForm1").on('submit',function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // to prevent default page reloading
                var dataString = $(this).serialize(); // to get the form data

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "send.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#contactForm1')[0].reset(); // to reset form data
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        Swal.fire(
  'Thank you!',
  'Your request has been accepted!',

)
                    }, 2000);

                });

            });

</script>
```

what could be the problem? Please help

Comment: Where is ajax function?

Comment: thank u for comment, i'm edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not sending request with AJAX.

**Solution:**

First remove `action="send.php"` from your form

then add this to your script.

```
<script>
  $('.button').click(function(){
    swal({
     title:"Red Stapler",
     text: "Are You Sure?",
     buttons: {
            cancel: true,
            confirm: "Submit"
     }
    }).then((value) => { 
       <!-- When the user click submit send Ajax request -->
       $.ajax({
          url:    "send.php",
          method: "POST",
          data:{
            message1: $(#message1).val(),
            message2: $(#message2).val(),
            message3: $(#message3).val()
          },
          success: function(data)
          {
             // some actions
          }
       });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: one more problem, when message send succesfully, how to make it close the modal form?

Comment: if you want to close your modal after sending request update your confirm button

 confirm: {
   text: "Submit",
   value: "Submit",
   closeModal: true
}

Comment: $('modal').close();

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can send it without ajax request also try this change

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
```

to

```js
function submitForm(){
```

your function will look like this:

```js
function submitForm(){
    swal({
        title:"Red Stapler",
        text: "Are You Sure?",
        buttons: {
            cancel: true,
            confirm: "Submit"
        }
    });
}
```

Now in the form add

```js
onsubmit="return submitForm()"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({ title: "Done", text: "Record updated successfully!", type: "success" }, function () {location.reload();});
```

Simply use this line code, it will automatically hide alert and reload the page when click "OK".